# How do I override the location in macOS location services?

Tags: macos, geolocation

How do I override the location in macOS location services?

As in, manually set it to whatever lat/long I choose?

I have root. It should be possible.

UPDATE: I have a MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.5.2

Comment: More info please: what Mac and what version of macOS?

Comment: Why? to use a different version of the Apple Shop?